# MySQL query - ORDER BY

Tags: sql, mysql

Can I do this?:

```
SELECT * FROM calendar ORDER BY ((month * 31) + day)
```

Comment: Do you have columns in your table called `month` and `day` or do you want these to be parsed out of a date field?

Comment: i have colums month and day (numerical)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes (assuming that you have numeric columns in your table called `month` and  `day`)

Wouldn't you want

```
SELECT * FROM calendar ORDER BY ((`month` * 31) + `day`)
```

though?

**Edit**

Actually just use

```
SELECT * FROM calendar ORDER BY `month`, `day`
```

Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: actually yes :D or any number higher than 31

Answer (score 2):

You can order by any column in your query result. If you can `SELECT` such on-the-fly prepared information then you can `ORDER BY` it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have columns in your table called `month` and `day`, then you should make a few changes to your query and it will work:

```
SELECT * FROM calendar ORDER BY ((month * 100) + day)
```

I removed the quotes from your column names and increased your month multiplier by one order of magnitude in order to ensure correct sorting on month and day numbers greater than or equal to 10. Also, I corrected a typo in the spelling of `ORDER`.

**BUT**

- Your query will not sort correctly by year (not sure if this matters in your use case).
- Your query will execute slowly on large data sets because of the dynamic nature of your `ORDER` by clause. Consider using a single date column and creating an index on it.